# script to copy folder structure to many folders

Tags: powershell, script

Scenario: I'd like to copy a folder structure (minus the root folder) to a series of existing folders.

Here is what I have for a script:

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem C:\test

foreach ($folder in $folders.name){
Copy-Item -Path "C:\folder structure\\*" -Destination C:\test\$folder -Recurse -Force -Verbose
}
```

This script works except it copies the root folder to the existing folder also. The * in the -Path should make it so that the root folder is not copied. Am I missing something?

Comment: Use Windows robocopy for this instead. It's specifically designed for such use cases. It can be done in PS, but just saying. You can of course use robocopy with PowerShell but not really required.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with the following structure where I want to copy the contents of /bar/ into each folder in /foo/:

```
C:\FOO
├───foo1
└───foo2
C:\BAR
├───bar1
│       test1.txt
└───bar2
        test2.txt
```

For the code you're close, but if you only want the folder contents then only grab the contents:

```
foreach ($folder in ( Get-ChildItem c:\foo ) ) { 
    Get-ChildItem C:\bar | 
    Copy-Item -Recurse -Destination "C:\foo\$($folder.Name)"
}
```

result:

```
C:\FOO
├───foo1
│   ├───bar1
│   │       test1.txt
│   └───bar2
│           test2.txt
└───foo2
    ├───bar1
    │       test1.txt
    └───bar2
            test2.txt
C:\BAR
├───bar1
│       test1.txt
└───bar2
        test2.txt
```

This is technically the same as using `*` after your folder path. That also works for me without creating the root folder. Check that you aren't using single quotes and that the command completes successfully by manually running `copy-item "C:\bar\\*" -recurse C:\foo\foo1 -whatif`. Double-check that you don't actually have a folder with the same name inside your root folder.